# How to define a cost function for the 'general state cost integral' optimization objective of OMPL through MoveIt?

Tags: optimization, moveit, state, function, ompl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm relatively new to OMPL and MoveIt, but I'm fairly certain that I understand the capabilities of OMPL and that there are no tutorials for this. Maybe I'm just missing something. I'm hoping someone might have an idea.

I want to use the general state cost integral optimization objective to plan movements for a UR5 robot arm. I know how to tell MoveIt to use this method (in ompl_planning.yaml), but I don't know where I need to define the cost function. Is it even possible at the moment?

Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266920/how-to-define-a-cost-function-for-the-%27general-state-cost-integral%27-optimization-objective-of-ompl-through-moveit?/) by [JHofmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/5261/jhofmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-20**:
I don't think this is supported in MoveIt right now, but let's wait on some other answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked and basically answered before on the moveit mailing list (but thanks for asking here!):

[Cost-optimization planning](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/ompl$20cost%7Csort:relevance/moveit-users/DKG9Z3x6J9s/P3Yh91yNDAAJ)

Related: [Planning direct path plans](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/moveit-users/ompl$20cost%7Csort:relevance/moveit-users/_C8ysk6vURg/-osufg4O8fUJ)

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2017-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1